# How do I pass a custom Codable Model into a Firebase Function?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What's the best way to pass a custom Codable Model into a firebase function? Here's what I have right now, but I get the error: `Unsupported type: __SwiftValue for value`

```
struct ExampleStruct: Codable {
    var hi: String
    var world: Int
    var last: [String]
}

let myModel = ExampleStruct(hi: "World", world: 1, last: ["hi world"])

functions.httpsCallable(FirebaseFunctionsNames.exampleName).call(["data":myModel]) { [weak self] (result, error) in
    print(result)
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following ended up solving my question (note: I wouldn't recommend the force unwraps and casts but it's easier to consume in StackOverflow this way :)

```
struct ExampleStruct: Codable {
    var hi: String
    var world: Int
    var last: [String]
}

let myModel = ExampleStruct(hi: "World", world: 1, last: ["hi world"])

func hiWorld(input: myModel) {
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try! jsonEncoder.encode(input)
    let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    functions.httpsCallable(FirebaseFunctionsNames.exampleName).call(["data":json]) { [weak self] (result, error) in
        print(result)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And then on the backend (Typescript):

```
const myModel = JSON.parse(data.data) as ExampleStruct;
```